# Charles Proxy certificate is installed on device but calls are blocked Android

Tags: android, charles-proxy

So I am trying to use Charles to test the analytics on this app. I've followed many tutorials but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've set up Charles properly, connected my Android phone (Google Pixel, Android 8) through the proxy, downloaded and installed the certificate. When I run the app I can see the tracking server, Charles filters the rest of them away, but the calls are blocked and instead I see a red "x" and this message:

> "SS Handshake Received fatal alert:certificate_unknown"

The certificate is installed to the device and trusted I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

It's also important to note that the security config file has been added to the app, but I am still getting this result.

Error example:

[image: error example]

Answer (score 0):

> It's also important to note that the security config file has been added to the app, but I am still getting this result.

Can you share your security config file? If that's configured to trust user-installed certificates then you shouldn't have this problem, so there may be something wrong there. Compare it with [this example](https://httptoolkit.tech/docs/guides/android#if-you-dont-have-a-custom-network-security-config).

Alternatively, this might be traffic from a different app on the device. Changing the proxy settings will redirect all traffic from the device, and other unmodified apps won't trust your certificate, so will cause these exact errors.